# Which class replace for "Zend_Validate" in Magento 2.4.6?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, validation, zend-framework, laminas

I have one function that uses the "Zend_Validate" Now I upgraded my Magento version to 2.4.6 and I got an error like..

https://prnt.sc/z3i-VQY7VFvp

with class replace

my code is

```
 if (!\Zend_Validate::is($email, \Magento\Framework\Validator\EmailAddress::class)) {
                $messages [] = __("Please enter a valid Email address on row [" . $rowIndex . "]");
                continue;
            }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here I mention some other Zend classes which Replace with laminas

1). \Zend_Http_Client::POST will be \Laminas\Http\Request::METHOD_POST and

2). \Zend_Http_Client::GET will be \Laminas\Http\Request::METHOD_GET

3). \Zend_Json with be \Laminas\Json\Json

4). \Zend_Filter replaced with laminas-filter

5). \Zend_HTTP replaced with laminas-http

6). \Zend_Validate replaced with laminas-validator

7). \Zend_Filter_Input replacement with as following given code

```
$inputFilter = new \Magento\Framework\Filter\FilterInput(
        ['date_from' => $this->dateFilter, 'date_to' => $this->dateFilter],
        [],
        $data
    );
```

Comment: A complete list is available at official guideline https://docs.laminas.dev/laminas-validator/validators/email-address/

Answer (score 5):

You can simply use `\Laminas\Validator\StaticValidator` and `execute()`. `execute()` method is same as old `is()`.

Example:

```
if (!\Laminas\Validator\StaticValidator::execute($email, 'EmailAddress')) {
      $messages [] = __("Please enter a valid Email address on row [" . $rowIndex . "]");
      continue;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this code,

```
use Magento\Framework\Validator\EmailAddress as EmailValidator;

// ...

if (!EmailValidator::isValid($email)) {
    $messages[] = __("Please enter a valid Email address on row [" . $rowIndex . "]");
    continue;
}
```

Comment: isValid function isn't static.

Answer (score 1):

> Zend usage deprecated since 2.4.6 Now you can use Laminas.

Comment: so for Zend_Validate which class I need to use

Comment: 1. Zend_Validate replaced with laminas-validator  

2. Zend_Filter replaced with laminas-filter

3. Zend_HTTP replaced with laminas-http

Answer (score 1):

**Zend_Validate replaced with laminas-validator**

The following modules are affected by this change:

1. Magento_Store
2. Magento_User
3. Magento_GoogleAdwords (backend)
4. Magento_Framework (translation and validation functionality)

Comment: Zend_Validate replaced with laminas-validator 2. Zend_Filter replaced with laminas-filter 3. Zend_HTTP replaced with laminas-http

Answer (score 0):

You should use Magento 2 api classes. This is the better practic.

```
use Magento\Framework\Validator\EmailAddress;
use Magento\Framework\Validator\ValidatorChain;
//
if (!ValidatorChain::is($email, EmailAddress::class)) {
   $messages [] = __("Please enter a valid Email address on row [" . $rowIndex . "]");
   continue;
}
```

Or Laminas classes

```
$validator = new \Laminas\Validator\EmailAddress();
if (!validator->isValid($email, \Magento\Framework\Validator\EmailAddress::class)) {
    $messages [] = __("Please enter a valid Email address on row [" . $rowIndex . "]");
    continue;
}
```

Magento class is extended from  Laminas.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Zend validations on many places in your custom extensions then you can install this using the command

```
composer require magento/zendframework1
```