# Zend replacement for Magento 2.4.6

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.6, zend

I have an old module that uses this in the constructor

`\Zend_Filter_Interface $templateProcessor`

Can anyone tell me what I can replace this with as it throws error on setup:di:compile when upgrading to 2.4.6

Answer (score 1):

Most of the `Zend` namespace can be replaced with `Laminas`.

In your specific case, `\Zend_Filter_Interface` can be replaced with `\Laminas\Filter\FilterInterface`

Answer (score 0):

You can replace with Magento\Framework\Filter\FilterInput. Like:

```
$inputFilter = new \Magento\Framework\Filter\FilterInput(
        ['date_from' => $this->dateFilter, 'date_to' => $this->dateFilter],
        [],
        $data
    );
```

you can also get help from this link :: [Which class replace for "Zend_Validate" in Magento 2.4.6?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/367184/which-class-replace-for-zend-validate-in-magento-2-4-6)